# ImportError: No module named Include

Tags: python, package

Attempting to run a program and keep receiving this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/pi/Desktop/IMU Python/Euler.py", line 5, in <module>
    from Include.IMU3 import IMU3

ImportError: No module named 'Include'
```

I have run `$python -m pip install --user include` so the package should be in place.

Comment: Are you running `Euler.py` in IDLE?

Comment: Try `from include.IMU3 import IMU3` (case-sensitive)

Comment: Running in Thonny IDE

Comment: Are the files in place? Is there a folder [Ii]nclude in your user files and within this folder a file named `__init__.py`? Check wether the installation folder of include is on the Python Path, which can be found in `sys.path` when you imported `sys`... Or you can simply enter `$PYTHONPATH` in bash.

Comment: @Daniel I verified that there was not a difference in packages Include v include and changed case in the code to further verify that there was not a difference.

Comment: Try running from CMD.

Comment: In addition to the above comments: Try `pip freeze` from the command line within your environment (especially if you are using a virtual environment) to verify that the package was `pip install`-ed correctly.

Comment: There is not a file _init_.py. There us only the _psycahce_ and the IMU3.py file.